# Can't pair 13" MacBook Air with iPhone 4 via Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I'm not sure why, but I can't get my iPhone 4 to talk to my new MacBook Air 13".  I turn bluetooth on for both devices, open the Bluetooth Preferences and pair the devices.  This works - the code is displayed on the Mac and the phone, I click OK and it looks busy.  After that I get a message on the iPhone saying "[mac name] is not supported".

I have also tried clicking 'Connect to Network' on the Mac and that results in the error "The Bluetooth network is unavailable: There was an error connecting to your device. Make sure the device is turned on and in range".

I'm running 10.7.2 and iOS 5.0.

Well the device (iPhone) is on and in range.  Can anyone help?  I want to be able to control Keynote on my Mac using the Keynote Remote app on my phone.

Comment: I've also tried pairing with my 27" iMac, also running Lion.  Same problem.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Have you followed [Apples instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3325#2)?

It seems that Keynote works better via WiFi than Bluetooth but the link above shows how to setup both.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem pairing Mac mini and Ipad with iPhone 3GS.

Turned out I had to enable Bluetooth AND Tethering on the iPhone. Suddenly it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to somebody as it relates to a very similar question:

My 27" Mac (purchased February 2012) would not stay paired with my iPad Air 2 (purchased new in January 2015) nor with my Samsung Galaxy S4 mobile phone (purchased November 2013).  They would pair for about 2 seconds, and then I got the message: "Network Access is unavailable. Make sure network access is enabled".
I have seen this issue on several blogs.
The answer is that my Mac was built before a time when Bluetooth Low Energy was supported.  That means it cannot connect to other devices by Bluetooth (apart from its own trackpad and wireless keyboard) and it cannot do Air Drop or any of today's similar functions - so hard luck, find another solution, such as Messaging, which does work via wireless.
To check for yourself, Click the Apple logo in the top left hand corner -> About This Mac -> Overview Tab -> System Report button -> Hardware -> Bluetooth -> and look for: " Bluetooth low energy supported".  If it says "NO" then you are in the same boat as myself and you will not be able to use the facility.

Hope this saves someone a headache.